# If f(n) = θ(g(n)), and for every , (),()≥ 2 then log(f(n)) = θ(log(g(n)))?

Tags: algorithm, big-o, complexity-theory

Is this statement **false**?
I couldn't find a answer to this question in this site (only for big O).

from the definition i can assume: `log⁡(C1g(n)) ≤ log⁡(f(n)) ≤ log⁡(C2g(n))`

i solved the right side: `log⁡(f(n)) ≤ log⁡(C2g(n)) ≤ log⁡(C2) + log⁡(g(n))`, Because `log⁡(g(n))>1`, there is `C2log⁡(g(n)) ≥ log⁡(C2 ) => log⁡(f(n)) ≤ C2log⁡(g(n)) + log⁡(g(n)) ≤ (C2+1)log⁡(g(n))`.

but i couldn't find a constant in the left side: `log(f(n)) ≥ log(C1g(n)) ≥ log⁡(C1) + log⁡(g(n)) ≥ log⁡(g(n))` let's say `C3log(g(n) < log(C1) C3 < log(C1)/log(g(n))` - is there a solution?

meaning i couldn't prove that `log(f(n)) = Ω(log(g(n)))`.
please, if you can, show me the complete proof.

Comment: Looking at your title, we dont have LaTeX support here (unfortunately).

Answer (score 1):

By definition:

```
c1*g(n) <= f(n) <= c2 g(n), for n > n0
```

as functions are positive and `log` is an increasing function, we can have the following:

```
log(c1*g(n)) <= log(f(n)) <= log(c2*g(n)), for n > n0
=> log(c1) + log(g(n)) <= log(f(n)) <= log(c2) + log(g(n)), for n > n0
```

Now, as `log(c1) + log(g(n)) <= log(f(n))`, if `c1 >= 1`, we can conclude that:

```
log(g(n)) <= log(f(n))
```

Hence the proof is complete (similarly for `log(f(n)) <= c2 * c1* log(g(n))` if `c2 >= 1`).

If `c1 < 1` (so, `log(c1) < 0`), we need to find a constant `c3 > 0` like the following:

```
c3 * log(g(n)) < log(c1) + log(g(n))
```

So,

```
 -log(c1) < (1-c3) log(g(n)) 
=> -log(c1)/(1-c3) <  log(g(n))
```

Now, as `g(n) >= 2` for every `n`, if we have the following:

```
-log(c1)/(1-c3) < log(2) = 1
```

we will satisfy the definition of `Omega`.
So, the following value for `c3` is valid for the definition:

```
-log(c1)/(1-c3) < 1
=> -log(c1) < 1- c3 => c3 < 1 + log(c1)
```

Also, if `log(c1) < -1`, we need to find a `m0`, such that `g(n) > k` for every `n > m0` and `-log(c1)/(1-c3) < k` has at leat one valid solution, i.e., `c3 < 1 + log(c1)/k`. In other words, we need to find `m0` and `k > 0` such that `g(n) > k` and `log(c1)/k > -1`. The former means the following:

```
log(c1) > -k => c1 > 2^(-k)
```

Comment: first of all thank you. from the last part, doesn't it mean that if there is n when gn , fn>=2 and a c1 that is < 2^(-k) the statement is false ? (i guess by e you meant 2)

Comment: meaning that there might be a c1 that log(c1) < -1 and f(n)=theta(g(n) but log(f(n)<>theta(log(g(n)))? making the statement false?

Comment: @Danny It's not possible. There are two scenarios. First, `f(n)` and `g(n)` has a constant limit when `n` goes to infinity. In that case, we can always find many constants that satisfy the inequalities. Otherwise, they go to infinity, in that case, as `c1` is constant, we can find such `k` that satisfies the corresponding inequality.

Answer (score 0):

The statement is indeed true. To begin with, we suppose `f(n)` and `g(n)` are both increasing functions that go to infinity as `n` grows large. Then by definition of bit theta, there exists constants `a` and `b` such that

`a*g(n)<=f(n)<=b*g(n)`

Taking logarithms on both side we have

`-log a+log g(n)<=log f(n)<=log g(n)+log b`

Without loss of generality let's assume `a<1` and `b>1` and `n` is large enough such that `g(n)>1`. As a result, we obtain the following inequality:

`log g(n)<=log f(n)<=(1+log b)log g(n)`

This indicates that `log f(n)` is big theta of `log g(n)`.